# Does linking to a Google Cloud Storage image, is counted as an operation?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, angular6

Does linking to a Google Cloud Storage image, is counted as an operation?

Something like this in Angular 6

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img src="{{image.url}}" alt="{{image.title}}"/>
</div>
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page will have to read the bucket to retrieve the image so yes, it will be counted as an operation. I'm also guessing that the image will be cached after the first read so only the first read by client will count.

If you are asking if that operation counts towards the pricing, then that would be a different question. Depending on the type of the bucket and its location, charges may vary. For example, if that Angular 6 app is in Google App Engine and located in the same continent as the bucket, [network operations between them would be free](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing)